# Bitmap from ImageView - always in corner of screen, not possible to move | Android Studio

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview

this is my very first experience here on stackoverflow :). I hope i don't break any rule with my first question.

I want to get color from bitmap but i have a problem with converting Imageview to Bitmap. Wherever i put my ImageView on screen, it's moving to (0,0) screen position after converting it to Bitmap. The worst thing is that this is not visible on screen, but when i try to catch color from 'empty' position it gives me "color". Im attaching screens because im sure im not understandable now :D.

[clicked on area where is invisible bitmap and catching color)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgFf2.png)

[clicked on area where bitmap is located but it doesn't catch color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXw0i.png)

I really don't know what is wrong. sitting whole week on this case and i registered here to ask you...

It may be stupid thing because im newbie. Thanks for any help...

public class Game extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private boolean isTouch = false;
private ImageView imageOpponent;
private Bitmap bitmap1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    ImageView imageAim = findViewById(R.id.imageAim);
    ImageView imageMove = findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    ImageView imageShoot = findViewById(R.id.imageShoot);
    ImageView imageBackground = findViewById(R.id.imageBackground);
    //FrameLayout shootingFrame = findViewById(R.id.shootingFrame);


    //Bitmap bitmap = imageBackground.getDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageBackground.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    imageOpponent = findViewById(R.id.imageOpponent);
    imageOpponent.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    imageOpponent.buildDrawingCache(true);


    TextView textX = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView textY = findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    //textX.setText(String.valueOf(xSize));

    image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            float xSize = image.getWidth();
            float ySize = image.getHeight();
            float xMaxShootingFrame = imageBackground.getWidth();
            float yMaxShootingFrame = imageBackground.getHeight();
            float xMoveSize = imageMove.getLayoutParams().width;
            float yMoveSize = imageMove.getLayoutParams().height;
            textY.setText(String.valueOf(xMaxShootingFrame));
            float X = (float) event.getX() - (xMoveSize/2);
            float Y = (float) event.getY() - (yMoveSize/2);
            float xCalculated = 100 * event.getX() / xSize;
            xCalculated = xCalculated/100;
            float yCalculated = 100 * event.getY() / ySize;
            yCalculated = yCalculated/100;
            int eventaction = event.getAction();

            //if ((X >= 0 && Y >= 0) || (X <= 100 && Y <= 100))
            if ((X >= (0-(xMoveSize/2)) && X <= (xSize-(xMoveSize/2)) && (Y >= (0-(yMoveSize/2)) && Y <= (ySize-(yMoveSize/2))))) {
                switch (eventaction) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        //Toast.makeText(Game.this, "ACTION_DOWN AT COORDS "+"X: "+X+" Y: "+Y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        imageMove.setX(X);
                        imageMove.setY(Y);
                        imageAim.setX(xMaxShootingFrame*xCalculated-xMoveSize/2);
                        imageAim.setY(yMaxShootingFrame*yCalculated-yMoveSize/2);
                        textX.setText(String.valueOf(xCalculated));
                        isTouch = true;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        //Toast.makeText(Game.this, "MOVE "+"X: "+X+" Y: "+Y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        imageMove.setX(X);
                        imageMove.setY(Y);
                        imageAim.setX(xMaxShootingFrame*xCalculated-xMoveSize/2);
                        imageAim.setY(yMaxShootingFrame*yCalculated-yMoveSize/2);
                        //textX.setText(String.valueOf(bitmap.getHeight()));
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        //Toast.makeText(Game.this, "ACTION_UP "+"X: "+X+" Y: "+Y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        imageMove.setX(X);
                        imageMove.setY(Y);
                        imageAim.setX(xMaxShootingFrame*xCalculated-xMoveSize/2);
                        imageAim.setY(yMaxShootingFrame*yCalculated-yMoveSize/2);
                        //textX.setText(String.valueOf(bitmap.getHeight()));
                        break;
                }
            }
            float xxx = imageAim.getX();
            float yyy = imageAim.getY();
            return true;
            }
        });


    imageShoot.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){

            bitmap1 = imageOpponent.getDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmapBackground = ((BitmapDrawable)imageBackground.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

            float xMoveSizex = imageAim.getLayoutParams().width;
            float yMoveSizey = imageAim.getLayoutParams().height;
            int x = (int)imageAim.getX() + ((int)xMoveSizex/2);
            int y = (int)imageAim.getY() + ((int)yMoveSizey/2);

            //Bitmap bitmap69 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap1, imageOpponent.getWidth(), imageOpponent.getHeight(), false);

                textX.setText(String.valueOf(bitmap1.getHeight()));
                textY.setText(String.valueOf(bitmap1.getWidth()));

                if (x <= bitmap1.getWidth() && y <= bitmap1.getHeight()) {
                    int pixel = bitmap1.getPixel(x, y);
                    int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
                    int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
                    int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
                    //if (redValue == 0 && blueValue == 0 && greenValue == 0){
                    //imageBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(redValue,greenValue,blueValue));
                    if (bitmap1.getPixel(x, y) == Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                        textY.setText("Black " + x + " " + y);
                    } else {
                        textY.setText("Any Color");
                    }
                }

            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: As a note that `getDrawingCache` is deprecated in API level 28 and because of  hardware-accelerated rendering might produce funny results. Instead try creating a new Canvas for the bitmap `Canvas bitmapCanvas = new Canvas();` and `bitmapCanvas.setBitmap(bitmap);` and then draw the view to the bitmapCanvas `v.draw(bitmapCanvas);`

Comment: First of all thank you for comment!

The problem is i can't use getPixel on bitmapCanvas... :\ or i don't know how to do it correctly...

Comment: You would `getPixel()` on the bitmap you have backed the Canvas with, this would be (`bitmap`) in the example I gave as shown in the `setBitmap` method, just like you are currently doing to `bitmap1` at the moment. you are drawing to the bitmap via the Canvas, instead of drawing to the possibly hardware accelerated canvas and trying to get back a bitmap from it.